# Tortoise SVN repo-browser, checkout over VPN

Tags: vpn, svn, tortoisesvn

I have a problem with repo-broswer and checkout with TortoiseSVN(1.7) over VPN(IPsec). For example when I want to check-out repository, all begins OK, but after few seconds(sometimes 10 files, sometimes 20, 50) speed drops to 0 Bytes/s and everything stops. In this moment I can not ping server with SVN server, or anything else. But when I close checkout window after few seconds everything is OK. Other SVN actions allways works fine(update, commit, revision graph, log), also I can download files from shares,... The only thing which does not work over my VPN is really SVN repo-browser and checkout... communication with SVN server on LAN without VPN works fine.
Please help me.

Thanks

EDIT:

server: Windows server 2003, Visual SVN server 2.5

client: Windows 7 Ultimate, Tortoise SVN 1.7.7

Comment: please provide client and server OS, and release version, also anything you see in the `/var/log/messages` or equivalent system log. Sometimes these types of problems can be related to MTU discovery, so I have suggested some steps in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you report is reminiscent of some MTU problems that I have heard about, but assuming that you are on windows, you can try the following troubleshooting steps;

try to ping the server, and gently increase the packet size until you get failures;

```
ping 1.1.1.1 -f -l 1300  <---increase this value until it fails
64 bytes from nuq04s09-in-f16.1e100.net (74.125.224.144): icmp_seq=8 ttl=58 time=3.02 ms
64 bytes from nuq04s09-in-f16.1e100.net (74.125.224.144): icmp_seq=5 ttl=58 time=3.12 ms

ping 1.1.1.1 -f -l 1350
64 bytes from nuq04s09-in-f16.1e100.net (74.125.224.144): icmp_seq=8 ttl=58 time=3.02 ms
64 bytes from nuq04s09-in-f16.1e100.net (74.125.224.144): icmp_seq=5 ttl=58 time=3.12 ms

ping 1.1.1.1 -f -l 1400
--- 192.168.0.44 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4999ms
```

show your mtu settings like so;

```
C:\>netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces

Idx Met MTU State Name
--- --- ----- ----------- -------------------
1 4275 4294967295 connected Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
9 4230 1500 disconnected Wireless Network Connection 2
21 50 1500 connected Dial-up Connection
8 4230 1500 disconnected Local Area Connection
```

Here are some tutorials, if MTU turns out to the be the issue;
http://networkadminkb.com/KB/a62/troubleshooting-mtu-path-discovery-issues-over-a-vpn-tunnel.aspx
http://www.tolaris.com/2010/04/08/troubleshooting-path-mtu-problems/

Comment: I have "Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set." message with 1400 Bytes. Then when I change router, answer is same but SVN works fine.

Comment: another hint: when I ping server with SVN server with "ping 192.168.x.x -t" I have standard response. Then I run svn repo-browser/checkout and response is "Request timed out"(repo-browser window is frozen). Then I close repo browser window and after some time(about one minute) server returns standard response again.

Comment: @Cicik did you ever get a resolution? I'm experiencing very similar symptoms on my VPN.

Comment: [Here the author found 1250 to be an appropriate setting for TunnelMTU in his case.](https://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2007-04/0743.shtml)